# Fix bat file opening programs inconsistently

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to make a bat file to open multiple programs except I get errors shown below.

For the T/F error it occurs when I press alt,Win keys and closes the restr window if I exit the cmd window.

Both spuds don't even appear

What types of code should be added or removed to make the file run without the original cmd window + errors shown? As well as make all the programs run automatically close after pressing a specific key

Errors:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/zkuzUEq]

[image: second error]

Code below:

```
@ECHO OFF

start D:\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe

start D:\VSeeFace\VSeeFace.exe""

start D:\Iriun-Webcam\Iriun-Webcam.exe

start D:\Chatty\Chatty.exe

start D:\restreamchat\RestreamChat.exe

start "D:\ync\Connector_64bit\Machan_YukarinatteConnector.exe /en"

start D:\spud\Spud-Keyboard.exe

start D:\spud\Spud-Mouse.exe

pause>nul
```

Answer (score 2):

The two errors are hard to make out in your screenshots, but they are both from OBS based on the logo.

> Failed to find locale/en-US.ini

and

> Failed to to load locale

These are caused by [launching OBS while not in the directory](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/2966#issuecomment-632097084).

> This is expected, we do not support running OBS from outside the current working directory.

To prevent this error, [you can run it with this command](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/2966#issuecomment-725838757):

**Note:** This is copied verbatim for quote purposes, **you will need to adjust the file path to where you have OBS installed and the flags being used.**

> ```
> start /d "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\" obs64.exe --startrecording --minimize-to-tray
> ```

Source: [obs-studio GitHub Issues](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/2966)

Some additional discussion on how to solve this issue can be found [on the OBS forums](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/bat-file-obs-failed-to-find-locale-en-us-ini-my-solution.131660/).

> The method that I found works for me, is to set the directory first, THEN call OBS to open up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when i tried it I get obs64.exe not found for both suggestions.

Comment: Syntax is `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`